# Is it possible to map list with a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have list of months as `months = ['JAN','FEB', 'MARCH', 'APR']` and list of dictionaries as

```
 month_dict = [JAN_dict, FEB_dict, MARCH_dict, APR_dict]
```

where in each month dictionary has 4 keys in it e.g. `JAN_dict.keys()` has `dict_keys(['df_contact_centre_JAN', 'df_digital_JAN', 'df_retail_JAN', 'df_network_JAN'])` keys and where each value corresponding to a key is a dataframe.

I want to create a dictionary where each month from `months` list  corresponds to entire dictionary of that corresponding month e.g.

```
final_dict =  {'JAN': 'df_contact_centre_JAN', 'df_digital_JAN', 'df_retail_JAN', 'df_network_JAN',
               "FEB' : 'df_contact_centre_FEB', 'df_digital_FEB', 'df_retail_FEB', 'df_network_FEB',
               'MARCH : 'df_contact_centre_MARCH', 'df_digital_MARCH', 'df_retail_MARCH', 
                        'df_network_MARCH',
               'APR' :  'df_contact_centre_APR', 'df_digital_APR', 'df_retail_APR', 'df_network_APR'}
```

where each value corresponding to final_dict is the dataframe which was corresponding to each key's value in month_dict

Comment: Your `final_dict` is syntactically illegal in Python. You cannot get a syntatically illegal thing. Please clarify your intention.

Comment: can you post all your data, your data frame  and your month_dicts?

Comment: As it is organization's data,I cannot share it

Comment: You do not have to show the actual data. Please show _similar_ data.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
month_dict = {
  'JAN': JAN_dict,
  'FEB': FEB_dict,
  etc
}
```

or possibly this, if you wanted the values of those dictionaries in a list:

```
month_dict = {
  'JAN': JAN_dict.values(),
  'FEB': FEB_dict.values(),
  etc
}
```

Comment: In general, SO users should not answer questions until they have a clear understanding of the OP's concerns.

Comment: Sounded pretty clear to me. Dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: You have two versions of the answer, the second is not a dict of a dict, and neither matches the expected output. So, I guess it is not so clear.